# JPM [error] Message: SyntaxError: duplicate label

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a firefox extension and am getting this error message. What does it mean?

The only `label` I have is from:

```
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "show-popup",
    label: "something that can't possibly be a duplicate",
    ...
```

Later on I add a background page:

```
require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
    contentScript: [ ... some scripts ... ]
});
```

While testing, I get the error:

```
> jpm run -b $(which firefox)
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on MyExtensionTitle
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
console.error: myextensiontitle: 
JPM [error]   Message: SyntaxError: duplicate label
```

This only happens when I add the background script. How can I debug further? All I have to go on is an ambiguous terminal message and no line number.

Answer (score 0):

A [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#contentScriptFile)'s `contentScript` is the source code. It should be `contentScriptFile` instead:

```
require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
    contentScriptFile: [ ... some scripts ... ]
});
```